# svelte rollup-plugin-css-only import not working

Tags: css, import, svelte, rollupjs

In a svelte project, I want to import some css files, and I cant make this plugin works : https://github.com/thgh/rollup-plugin-css-only

here is my config

`project/rollup.config.js`

```js
/* other imports */
import css from 'rollup-plugin-css-only';

export default {
  plugins: [
    /* svelte here, */
    css({ output: 'public/build/extra.css' }),
    /*
      alternatives I tried :
    css(),
    css({ output: 'extra.css' }),
    css({ output: 'bundle.css' }),
    css({ output: 'public/build/bundle.css' }),
    */
  ]
};
```

I put intentionally the output in a separate file `project/public/build/extra.css` instead of the default `project/public/build/bundle.css` to see if the file will be created; and the file is never created

I searched with `find . -type f -name "*extra.css"` in the project root directory

the output file is included inside the `project/public/index.html` :

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/build/extra.css'>
```

and that gives me a log with error 404, which is normal if it was not created

I tried different ways to import :

`project/src/component/exemple.css`

inside the component :

`project/src/component/exemple.svelte`

```
<script>
  import './my_style.css';
</script>
```

```
<style>
  @import './my_style.css';
</style>
```

```
<style src='./my_style.css'>
</style>
```

the plugin is present in the package.json, and I did `npm install --save-dev rollup-plugin-css-only`

Answer (score 0):

ok my bad, the problem was simple : I didn't re run the npm start command, because I misconfigured my docker, so the changes in `rollup.config.js` couldn't take place :p

so dumb

by the way, I shouldn't include the `public/build/` into the path, this will only create a nested `public/build/` folder inside the `public/build/` folder

and also, the output file can be `bundle.css`, it will add the css to the bundle.css file, no need for an extra file

finally, this wil produce a global css, not a scoped one